# PHP OOP code works well. Is it correct practice? Will some future release break it?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

Code snippet for `class lnemail_fetch`

```
<?php  Part of heritage_classes.php
// Declare classes
class lnemail_fetch {
// return string in format "title | factoid" 
    public  $result;
    public function get_ln_info() 
    {
    include ("./includes/LOheritage-config.php");
    mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die(mysql_error());
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lnemail";
     $result = mysql_query($query);
         $this->result = $result;
    }
}
?>
```

Code Snippet from larger program  It lists a MySQL table

```
    require_once('./includes/heritage_classes.php'); 

    $newlnemail_fetch = new  lnemail_fetch;
     $newlnemail_fetch->get_ln_info();
     $newresult  = $newlnemail_fetch->result;
     echo  "lnemail File display  <br />"; 

      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($newresult))
        {
         echo $row['ln_email']. "  |  " . $row['ln_date'] . "  |  " . $row['ln_week'] ;
          echo "<br />";

        }
```

Is this use of PHP OOP considered good practice even though it works nicely for now?

Comment: If you're trying to use object-oriented programming and you're not using the object-oriented interface of `mysqli` or PDO, then you have some work to do. Also, there's no point in writing your own database wrapper when there are [dozens of them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library) that are already written.

Comment: Asking if a future release of PHP will break your code is like asking if Apple will release the iPad mini in 2 weeks, or will the world end this year. No one knows, we have to wait until the day comes ;-)

Comment: Just because you used a class doesn't mean your code is object-oriented...you're using a class and methods, that's all.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0):

I would say no, it's no good use of OOP.

Areas for improvement:

Separate the db connection and query stuff.
Separate the db result handling. Implementing a result object that is iterable will be a good idea.
Not using the mysql extension and switching to mysqli is a very good idea. It will also give you an OOP interface to MySQL for free.

Probably aspects of escaping input inside SQL strings should be considered, but this is undecidable because no such code has been shown.

Answer (score 0):

> Will some future release break it?

Yes, because you are using the old and (now) deprecated [`mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

> Code snippet for class `lnemail_fetch`

The name `lnemail` is not really a good name for a class, because when I look at it I have no idea what `ln` means. Also class names are often `UpperCamelCased` and methods `camelCased`.

Now to actually look at your code:

When looking at your class it is just a class and currently has nothing to do with OOP. What I would have done is make the `$result` property private, because currently your is simply some container for data. Also I would introduce another class which will be reponsible for accessing the data from the database (or whatever storage you have). I would also introduce another class to represent a single email and an factory class to build these mail objects. This would look something like the following:

// not sure whether inbox is the correct name, because I don't really have a good idea of what the class represents

```
class Inbox
{
    private $storage;

    private $mailFactory;

    public function __construct($storage, $mailFactory)
    {
        $this->storage     = $storage;
        $this->mailFactory = $mailFactory;
    }

    public function fetchAllMails()
    {
        $mailRecordset = $this->storage->fetchAll();

        $mails = array();
        foreach ($mailRecordset as $mailRecord) {
            $mails[] = $this->mailFactory->create($mailRecord);
        }

        return $mails;
    }
}

class InboxStorage
{
    private $dbConnection;

    public function __construct(\PDO $dbConnection)
    {
        $this->dbConnection = $dbConnection;
    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        $stmt = $this->dbConnection->query('SELECT * FROM lnemail');

        return $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}

class Email
{
    private $email;

    private $date;

    private $week;

    public function __construct($email, $date, $week)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->date = $date;
        $this->week = $week;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function getWeek()
    {
        return $this->week;
    }
}

class EmailFactory
{
    public function create($record)
    {
        return new Email($record['email'], $record['date'], $record['week']);
    }
}
```

And you can run it like following:

```
// initialize all the objects we are going to need
$emailFactory = new EmailFactory();
$dbConnection = new \PDO('mysql:dbname=dbtest;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$inboxStorage = new InboxStorage($dbConnection);
$inbox = new Inbox($inboxStorage, $mailFactory);

// run the code
foreach($inbox->fetchAllMails() as $email) {
    echo $mail->email . ' | ' . $mail->date . ' | ' . $mail->week . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not really a true class because `lnemail_fetch` isn't an object. All you are doing is making a container and having to make the container merely to call a function that could be static and return the result rather than assign it.

A better class might include the newer `mysqli` rather than the dated mysql and work as follows. It makes the rows into objects with the columns being properties (variables;

```
<?php
class lnemail {
    public $ln_emai;
    public $ln_date;
    public $ln_week;

    public static function Fetch($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname) {
      $db = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname) or die(mysql_error());
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lnemail";
      $result = $db->query($query);
      $returnArr = array();
      while($obj = $result->fetch_object('lnemail') {
         $returnArr[] = $obj;     
      }
      return $returnArr;
    }
}
```

Then

```
 <?php
 require_once("./includes/LOheritage-config.php");
 require_once('./includes/heritage_classes.php');
 $lnemails = lnemail::Fetch($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
 echo  "lnemail File display  <br />";
 foreach($obj as $lnemail) {
      echo $obj->ln_email. "  |  " . $obj->ln_date . "  |  " . $obj->ln_week;
      echo "<br />";
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Philip for the nice reply.  I'm busy testing and debugging the code.